# How do I get user input in python (Kivy framework)

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, android-wifi, kivymd

I am trying to make a software in python (Kivy framework), my software will be capable of testing how strong are wifi passwords.

I have encountered a issue. How do I get the user input in my .kv (kivy) file to my .py (python) file?

**.PY FILE**:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
try:
    from wifidroid.wifi import WifiManager
except:
    pass
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
import kivymd, kivy
try:
    import wifidroid
except:
    pass
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button

text = 'testttt'

try:
    wifi = WifiManager()
    wifi.startScan()
    wifi.EnabledWifi(True)
    for i in range(wifi.ScanResults.size()):
        ssid = [wifi.ScanResults.get(i).SSID]
        bssid = [wifi.ScanResults.get(i).BSSID]
        levell = [wifi.ScanResults.get(i).level]
        text += ssid[0] + " " + bssid[0] + " " + str(levell[0])
except:
    pass

try:
    wifi.ConnectWifiWpa("WifiName", "WifiPassword")
except:
    pass



#wifi.ConnectWifiWep("WifiName", "WifiPassword")
#wifi.ConnectWifiPublic("WifiName")

class Layout_For_App(FloatLayout):
    output = StringProperty()
    input = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.label_output.text = text
        self.output = text


    pass


class AndrdWifiApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Layout_For_App()


AndrdWifiApp().run()
```

**.KV FILE**:

```
<Layout_For_App>:
    Label:
        text: 'Developed By Anonymous'
        pos_hint: {"x":0,"y":0.45}

    Label:
        text: 'OUTPUT' + root.output
        id: label_output
        background_color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
        size_hint: (0.451, 0.7)
        pos_hint: {"x":0.27,"y":0.17}
        valign: "middle"
        halign: "left"
        color: (0,1,0)
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: self.background_color
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        border: 3, 3
    Button:
        text: 'CRACK'
        background_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
        color: 0, 1, 1
        size_hint: (0.4, 0.15)
        pos_hint: {"x":0.0199,"y":0.01}
        font_size: 30

    TextInput:
        text: 'Enter Wifi SSID'
        id: input_value
        size_hint: (0.5, 0.15)
        pos_hint: {'x':0.49,'y':0.01}
        font_size: 40
```

I want to get the user input from my **.KV** file, then store it in a **VARIABLE** in my **.PY** file

[This picture explains more, and it also displays how my GUI software looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjr2E.png)

Comment: You don't 'store user input in variables in .py files' - a variable in a Python source code file is something you as the programmer use to remember and refer to stuff - by the time your user gets their hands on the software, all variables have been defined and your program should work as intended. What do you want to do with the user input? What does the user need to happen?

Comment: I want to use it as the wifi SSID (Wifi name)

Comment: Then connect to wifi

Answer (score 0):

In your `Layout_For_App` class you can add a method something like:

```
def get_ssid(self):
    self.ssid = self.ids.input_value.text  # store the input in a variable
```

And using your `Button` in the `kv` as an example, you can trigger that method whenever the `Button` is pressed:

```
Button:
    text: 'CRACK'
    background_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
    color: 0, 1, 1
    size_hint: (0.4, 0.15)
    pos_hint: {"x":0.0199,"y":0.01}
    font_size: 30
    on_press: root.get_ssid()  # trigger the storage of user input.
```